# WPF something wrong with my List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my function.

```
public List<DiseaseSymptomParams> GetSelectedDiseaseSymptom()
{
    var entiParams = new DiseaseSymptomParams();
    var selectedDiseases = new List<DiseaseSymptomParams>();

    try
    {
        foreach (DiseaseSymptom itemSelected in DiseaseSymptomsDataGrid.ItemsSource)
        {
            var cellContent = (CheckBox)StatusIdColumn.GetCellContent(itemSelected);
            if (cellContent != null && cellContent.IsChecked == true)
            {
                entiParams.Id = DefaultValue.GetInt(itemSelected.Id);
                selectedDiseases.Add(entiParams);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    return selectedDiseases;
}
```

Apparently, if I selected 2 or more items (using checkbox) all of the checked boxes will be added to `selectedDiseases` but the last one that has been added overrides all of the entries in the List.

Comment: I would get rid of the try/catch doing that is a really bad coding design. If you are worried about a casing error do `var cellContent = StatusIdColumn.GetCellContent(itemSelected) as CheckBox;` instead.

Comment: An empty catch block should only be used in very rare cases (eg logging a caught exception to multiple places and wanting to ignore if one fails). Even if you think there's a specific failure you want to ignore, catch the correct exception type. Your code above would ignore Out of memory exceptions, Thread abort exceptions, etc, etc, etc. This will come back to bite you in future.

Comment: I just removed the catch codes because stackoverflow prevented me of posting this, saying my post is just mostly codes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only have one copy of `entiParams` you keep modifying and re-adding to the list. Put the creation of the object inside the loop so you are making new ones instead of modifing old ones.

```
foreach (DiseaseSymptom itemSelected in DiseaseSymptomsDataGrid.ItemsSource)
{
    var cellContent = (CheckBox)StatusIdColumn.GetCellContent(itemSelected);
    if (cellContent != null && cellContent.IsChecked == true)
    {
        var entiParams = new DiseaseSymptomParams();
        entiParams.Id = DefaultValue.GetInt(itemSelected.Id);
        selectedDiseases.Add(entiParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet mother of milk! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

entiParams is a reference type and the list selectedDiseases keeps adding the same instance. Do this instead:

```
public List<DiseaseSymptomParams> GetSelectedDiseaseSymptom()
{
    var selectedDiseases = new List<DiseaseSymptomParams>();

    try
    {
        foreach (DiseaseSymptom itemSelected in DiseaseSymptomsDataGrid.ItemsSource)
        {
            var cellContent = (CheckBox)StatusIdColumn.GetCellContent(itemSelected);
            if (cellContent != null && cellContent.IsChecked == true)
            {
                var entiParams = new DiseaseSymptomParams
                {
                    Id = DefaultValue.GetInt(itemSelected.Id)
                };
                selectedDiseases.Add(entiParams);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    return selectedDiseases;
}
```